# jQuery to Toggle a form in a div, prevent hiding when clicking on inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Sorry if this has been asked, I am not sure how to best word it so I couldn't find a result on Google.

I currently have a div #divForm with some text and a table that has a form inside.  I currently have it so when you click on the div it toggles to show the table:

```
$("#divForm").live('click', function () {
            $(this).attr('class', 'closeForm');
            $(this).find("table.formTable").slideDown();
        });
```

The code that hides the div is as follows:

```
$(".closeForm").live ('click', function () {
            $(this).attr('id', 'divForm');
            $(this).find("table.formTable").slideUp();
        });
```

This works.  However, because there are inputs in the table/form, which is inside the div, clicking on the inputs to enter information causes the table to hide.

What is the best way to have it so the table/forms hides when clicking anywhere in the div EXCEPT when clicking on an input?

Comment: You should implement a visible clickable button/element for closing it.  It is highly counter-intuitive to hide the form if they click outside one of the edit boxes.  A lot of people are click-happy, myself included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your layout, but if `.closeForm` is the click target you could check the actual event target using [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) like this:

```
$(".closeForm").live('click', function (e) {
  if($(e.target).is(":input")) return;
  $(this).attr('id', 'divForm');
  $(this).find("table.formTable").slideUp();
});
```

Comment: @Josh - Welcome :)  Be sure to accept answers on this and your previous questions if they're resolved via the check-mark beside the answer that helped most :)